# Redirect sed file to a another directory under a new name

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed, files

I have a `$template` file that will invoke `sed` to do some templating. after this is done I want to redirect the new `$template` file to another directory named `output` and the new file name will be `newtemplate`.
portion of my shell script:

```
        sed -r -i.bak -e "{
            # templating done here.
        }" $template > $data/$newtemplate
```

this successful creates a file `$newtemplate` to the `$output` directory but it doesn't invoke sed or does any templating.
So in short, how do I use `sed` on the `$template` file and then take the templated file and redirect it to `output` directory under the new name `newtemplate`

Comment: Why are you using the `-i` option if you want to create another file, with a different name?

Comment: what should I use? still new to this

Comment: People: this is a perfectly clear question where the OP has shown what they are trying to do. Yes, it's a simple error, but we were all newbies once. There's no reason to downvote  just because the mistake was trivial. Nothing is trivial when you're learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i` option of `sed` means it won't produce any output. Instead, it will modify the original file in place. So your command is working fine, it is doing whatever `#templating` is, but it is doing it to `$template`, there is no output. Since there is no output, `> $data/$newtemplate` is just creating an empty file.

If you don't want to affect the original `$template` file and, instead, you want the output of the `sed` command to be printed to standard output and, therefore, into the file you redirect standard output to with `> $data/$newtemplate`, then you need to remove the `-i` option:

```
sed -r -e "{
            # templating done here.
        }" "$template" > "$data/$newtemplate"
```

(you also should [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222) as I did above)